# Can we use Opencv to get live video stream over the internet? How to do that?

Tags: url, video, opencv, camera, ip

I tried giving cvCreateCameraCapture an URL of the camera viewing on internet. 
However, I can't get any video playing.

I am writing in C language.

Answer (score 2):

My camera works to a degree with

```
CvCapture *camera = cvCreateFileCapture("rtsp://username:password@ip:port/ch1-s1");
```

Notice that I am using rtsp as opposed to http, I do have another camera that uses the http protocol but I'm not using this one at the moment.

So yes it is possible however different cameras use different urls and even then it is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, *we* can't. OpenCV is not made for that purpose.

[Video streaming using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825338/video-streaming-using-c)

> **cvCreateCameraCapture**
>
> Initializes capturing video from
>   camera
>
> **CvCapture* cvCreateCameraCapture( int index );**
>
> index
>       Index of the camera to be used. If there is only one camera or it does
>   not matter what camera to use -1 may
>   be passed.
>
> The function cvCreateCameraCapture
>   allocates and initialized the
>   CvCapture structure for reading a
>   video stream from the camera.

Check the [documentation](http://www.ai.rug.nl/vakinformatie/pas/content/Highgui/opencvref_highgui.htm#decl_cvCreateCameraCapture).

Comment: I read through it again. Yes, no wonder I find for two days yet I can't find any sample using OpenCV for this purpose.

Comment: However, do you have any recommendation, what library I can use to get live video stream on my iphone directly from the network camera

Comment: Also, there's a bunch of questions like yours, pick one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217191/stream-video-from-the-server-iphone-sdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978405/writing-an-app-to-stream-video-to-iphone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504992/iphone-video-camera-streaming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464732/how-do-i-stream-video-and-play-ithttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060097/streaming-a-video-on-iphone-and-then-storing-it-on-the-device

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (not yet) use OpenCV for this, I think.

For C++ based applications, you can also use cv::VideoCapture class to create capture object and then >> operator to grab + output your stream frame-by-frame. I have my own website where I have posted a file called [VideoWithOpenCV.cpp](http://tinyurl.com/asm4ecp). you can get it to see how to do that.

The reason I got curious in your question is that I wanted to make an android app in OpenCV to stream video to my fiance but unfortunately couldn't get anywhere. If you get any luck, let me know.