# read ip camera from openCV in C

Tags: url, video, opencv, camera, ip

I am trying to catch the mjpeg from an ip camera in openCV
but without success till now.
I have the url which displays the mjpeg video in firefox browser
"http://192.168.2.15/GetData.cgi"
but i cannot take it in opencv
Any ideas or solutions are welcomed...

Kind Regards

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we use Opencv to get live video stream over the internet? How to do that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768429/can-we-use-opencv-to-get-live-video-stream-over-the-internet-how-to-do-that)

Answer (score 0):

You need the data to be present locally either via the hard drive or in RAM. It would be slow, but I would recommend writing a web service to download frames of the video to the hard drive and then read them into opencv.